# Looking to get started with FPGAs -- speed up?

Tags: fpga

I'm very interested in learning FPGA development. I've found a bunch of "getting started with FPGA" questions here, and other tutorials and resources on the internet. But I'm primarily interested in using FPGAs as an accelerator, and I can't figure out what devices will actually offer a speed up over a desktop CPU (say a recent i7).

My particular interest at the moment is cellular automata (and other parallel environments like neural networks and agent based modeling). I'd like to experiment with 3d or higher dimensional cellular automatas. My question is - will the low-cost $100-$200 starter kits provide something that have potential to produce a significant speed up over a desktop CPU? Or would I need to spend more and get a higher end model FPGA?

Comment: More suited for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: There isn't a single external device that will offer better performance than a modern `i7`, except a modern `xeon` processor. Other than the fact that FPGAs are comparatively slow, the interface buses also add considerable latency. It's okay to say "I'm just doing this to learn"

Comment: Buy a bunch of graphics cards.

Comment: I was going to write a Life game on my Spartan 3 demo board, but after writing the logic for the cell I noticed it's functionally identical to someone else's. (2 LUTs splitting the 8 input bits into two 4 bit lookups, add the result, and one LUT to decode that into the next state). Nothing new. Anyway... it depends on the kind of automata. Most would PROBABLY be best served with CUDA/OpenCL on graphics cards. I think I recall CUDA had ways to organize in 3D... although I'm not sure how efficient the extra dimension would be. You'd think fluid dynamics would require that, so it's probably fast.

Comment: In order to get the same "power" as a desktop i7, you ave to look into high-end FPGAs such as Virtex 7 or Stratix 5, the rice of such devices are in $2k and up and the cheapest development board you can get with one of those boards costs about $4k. So unless you really need something that can't be done by CUDA or CPU, then I would suggest you forget about FPGAs.

Comment: Ok, I've been wooed by a bunch of papers/articles I've found online demonstrating significant speed up obtainable by using FPGAs for a wide range of highly parallelizable problems. And every time I look into GPGPU approaches (for neural networks, CAs, monte carlo Go game simulations, etc), memory latency issues always come up. There appears to be a lot of "black magic"/wizardry involved in creating performant GPU applications for problems that are parallel, but not completely separable... I'm not willing to pay $2K+ for a high end FPGA though, so I'll try to go the GPU route.

Answer (score 2):

The FPGA can be a very good accelerator, but (and this is a big BUG) it is usually is very expensive. We have here machines like the beecube, a convey or from Dini godzillas part time nanny, and they are all very expensive (>10k$) and even with these machines many applications can be better accelerated with a standard cpu cluster or gpus. That FPGA is a bit better when the total cost of ownership is considered as you have there usually a better engery efficiency.

But there are applications that you can accelerate. On the lower scale you can/should do an rough estimate if its worth for you application, but you need there more concrete numbers for your application. Consider an standard deskop cpu: usually it has at least 4 cores (or dual with hyperthreading, not to mention the vector units), and clocks at, say 3 GHz. This results in 12 GCycles per second computation power. The (cheap) FPGAs  you can get to 250 MHz (better can reach up to 500 MHz, but that must be very friendly designs and very good speed grades), so you need approx. 50 Operations in parallel, to compete with the CPU (actually its a bit better because the cpu has usually not 1 cycle ops, but it also has vector operations so we are equal).

50 Operations sounds much, and is hard, but is doable (the magic word here is pipeling). So you should know exactly how you are going to implement you design in hardware and which degree of parallelism you can use.

Even if you solve that parallelism problem, we come now to the real problem: The memory.

Above mentioned accelerators have so much compute capacity, they could do thousands things in parallel, but the real problem with such computation power is: how to get the data into/out of them. And you also have this problem in your small scale. In your desktop PC the cpu transfers more than 20GB/s to/from memory (good GPU card make 100GB/s and more), while your small accelerator for 100-200$ has at most (when you get lucky) 1-2 GB/s per PCI-Exp.

If its worth for you, depends completely on your application (and here you need far more details than: 3D Cellular Automatas, you must know the neighbourhoods, the required precision (do you double, single float, or integers or fixpoint...?), and your use case (do you transfer initial cell values, let the machine compute 2 day, and than transfer cell values back, or do you need the cell values after every step (this makes a huge difference in the required bandwidth while computation)).

But overall, without knowing more, I would say: Its 100$-200$ worth.

But not because you can compute your cellular automatas faster (which I dont believe), but because you will lern. And you will not only learn to design hardware and the development on FPGAs, but I see with our students that we have here, always that they get with the hardware design knowledge also a far better understanding on how the hardware actually look and behaves like. Sure nothing what you do on your FPGA is direct related to the interior of the cpu, but many get a better feeling for what hardware in general is capable of, which in turn make them even more effective software developer.

But I have also to admit: You are going to pay a much higher price than just the 100-200$: You have to spent really much time on it.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work for a reconfigurable system developer/manufacturer.

A short answer to your question "will the low-cost $100-$200 starter kits provide something that have potential to produce a significant speed up over a desktop CPU" is probably not.

A longer answer:

A microprocessor is a set of fixed, shared functional units tuned to perform reasonably well across a broad range of applications. The operating system and compilers do a good job of making sure that these fixed, shared functional units are utilized appropriately.

FPGA based systems get their performance from dedicated, dense, computational efficiency. You create exactly what you need to execute your application, no more, no less - and whatever you create is not shared with any other user, process, operating system, whatever. If you need 80 floating point units, you create 80 dedicated floating point units that run in parallel. Compare that to a microprocessor scheduling floating point operations across some smaller number of floating point units. To get performance faster than a microprocessor, you have to instantiate enough dedicated FPGA-based functional units to make a performance difference vs. a microprocessor. This often requires the resources in the larger FPGA devices.

An FPGA alone is not enough. If you create a large number of efficient computational engines in an FPGA you -have- to keep these engines fed with data. This requires some number of high bandwidth connections to large amounts of data memory around the FPGA. What you often see with I/O based FPGA cards is some of the potential performance gain is usually diminished by moving data back and forth across the I/O bus.

As a data point, my company uses the '530 Stratix IV FPGA from Altera. We surround it with several directly coupled memories and tie this subsystem directly into the microprocessor memory. We get several advantages over microprocessor systems for many applications, but this is not a $100-$200 starter kit, this is a full-blown integrated system.